# How can I push non removable/swipeable push notification

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a flutter application, but I want to achieve non swipeable/removable push notification.So how can I achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe this tutorial of "[Flutter Push Notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://morioh.com/p/85f8d5c32256)"could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve my answer through flutter_local_notification plugin
In that plugin, onGoing Notification facility is present so we can use it and enjoy ongoing notification